# Compare the same id with 2 values in string in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, conditional-aggregation

I have a table like this:

| id | status | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Overall | A |
| 123 | Current | B |
| 234 | Overall | B |
| 234 | Current | D |
| 345 | Overall | C |
| 345 | Current | A |

May I know how can I display how many ids is fitting with the condition: 
The grade is sorted like this A > B > C > D > F, 
and the Overall grade must be greater than or equal to the Current grade

Is it need to use CASE() to switch the grade to a number first? 
e.g. A = 4, B = 3, C = 2, D = 1, F = 0

In the table, there should be 345 is not match the condition. How can I display the tables below:

| qty_pass_the_condition | qty_fail_the_condition | total_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

and\

| fail_id |
| --- |
| 345 |

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the column indicating the sort order? WIthout it the DB returns the records in unrelyable order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As grade is sequential you can do `order by desc` to make the number. for the first result you can do something like below

```
select 
sum(case when GradeRankO >= GradeRankC then 1 else 0 end) AS 
qty_pass_the_condition,
sum(case when GradeRankO < GradeRankC then 1 else 0 end) AS 
qty_fail_the_condition,
count(*) AS total_ids
from
(
select * from (
select Id,Status,
Rank() over (partition by Id order by grade desc) GradeRankO
from YourTbale
) as a where Status='Overall'
) as b

inner join

(
select * from (
select Id,Status,
Rank() over (partition by Id order by grade desc) GradeRankC
from YourTbale
) as a where Status='Current'
) as c on b.Id=c.Id
```

For second one you can do below

```
select 
b.Id fail_id
from
(
select * from (
select Id,Status,
Rank() over (partition by Id order by grade desc) GradeRankO
from Grade 
) as a where Status='Overall'
) as b

inner join

(
select * from (
select Id,Status,
Rank() over (partition by Id order by grade desc) GradeRankC
from Grade 
) as a where Status='Current'
) as c on b.Id=c.Id

where GradeRankO < GradeRankC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty simple conditional aggregation for this, there is no need for window functions.

- A `Pass` is when the row of `Overall` has `grade` which is less than or equal to `Current`, with "less than" being in A-Z order.
- Then aggregate again over the whole table, and `qty_pass_the_condition` is simply the number of non-nulls in `Pass`. And `qty_fail_the_condition` is the inverse of that.

```sql
SELECT
  qty_pass_the_condition = COUNT(t.Pass),
  qty_fail_the_condition = COUNT(*) - COUNT(t.Pass),
  total_ids = COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      Pass = CASE WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Overall' THEN t.grade END) <=
                       MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Current' THEN t.grade END)
                  THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.id
) t;
```

To query the actual failed IDs, simply use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT
  t.id
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.id
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Overall' THEN t.grade END) >
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Current' THEN t.grade END);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/jOzpIF5t)